# Verify the divergence theorem for this surface and vector field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, gaussian-integral

Define the vector field $F(x,y,z) = (2xy+z)\hat i + y^2\hat j - (x+3y) \hat k$ and let the surface S be the closed surface consisting of the boundry of the solid enclosed by the four planes: $2x+2y+z=6$ , $x=y=z=0$. Verify the divergence theorem.

So I was able to find the value for the divergence side of the equality and I got 216. I am have trouble solving for the side of: 
$$\iint_{S} \vec{F}\,\dot \,dS\,$$
I know that when $z=0$ then $0 \le x \le3$ and $0\le y\le 3-x$.
Also when $y=0$ then $0 \le x \le3$ and $0\le z\le 6-2x$. 
And when $x=0$ then $0 \le y \le3$ and $0\le z\le 6-2y$. But I do not know how to do the left side of the equality still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of the solid is given by four triangles. You have to evaluate the [surface integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields) over each of them with respect to the vector field $\vec{F}$:

1) Triangle in the $xy$-plane: $z=0$, $2x+2y\leq 6$, $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$ with exterior normal vector $\vec{n_1}=(0,0,-1)$ then
$$\iint_{S_1} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=\iint_{S_1}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n_1} \,dxdy
=\int_{x=0}^3\int_{y=0}^{3-x}(x+3y) \,dydx=?$$

Can you take it from here?

P.S. Are you sure that the value for the divergence side of the equality is 216? Please check it again.
$$\int_V\text{div}(\vec{F})dV=\int_{x=0}^3\int_{y=0}^{3-x}\int_{z=0}^{6-2x-2y}(2y+2y+0)dzdydx=?$$

Comment: I think you meant $dydx$ instead of $dxdy$ . I see it more clearly now but I only see 3 surface integral in where I would find $dzdx$ and $dzdy$ which once am I missing? And you were right I made a computation error for my divergence thank you.

Comment: What did you get for these 3 surface integrals? The fourth one is $z=6-2x-2y$, $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, $z\geq 0$.  To evaluate it see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields What is the your new result for the divergence side?

Comment: My new result for the divergence side was 27. For the surface integrals I got 27, 18, -18 and 0 so it checks out. Thank you so much!